# Combining cross - entropy functions

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, tensors

I have the following two cross-entropy loss functions:
$$x - x z + \log(1 + \exp(-x))$$
and for $x<0$
$$-x z + \log(1 + \exp(x))$$

where, $z$ is a value between $[0,1]$ and $x$ is a logit. And, both of the above equations have range $[0, \infty]$
Now, the combined formula is $$\max(x, 0) - x z + \log(1 + \exp(-|x|))$$

However, I'm not quite sure about why there is an absolute value inside the `exp`.

The actual math is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/600caf99897e82cd0db8665acca5e7630ec1a292/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py) from tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work it out. When $x>0$, $|x|=x$, you immediately recover the first formula. If $x<0$, then you get $|x|=-x$, giving:

$$0-xz+\log(1+\exp(x))$$

Comment: OO! that makes perfect sense. I was for some reason trying to get back the first equation by plugging in x < 0.